# I just installed 12.10 and how do I update unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, 12.10

I can't access the launcher, unity, or anything and have to use basic terminal commands to do anything. I keep getting this error when trying to update manually:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libtiff5:i386 (> 4.0.0-1~) but it is not installed
 libsane:i386 : Depends: libtiff5:i386 (> 4.0.0-1~) but it is not installed
 libtiff4:i386 : Depends: libjbig0:i386 but it is not installed
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: We need more information about your graphics card, hardware, etc.

Comment: This isn't hardware related, this is probably a botched upgrade or something.

Answer (score 0):

try  :

- sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop , 
       sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
- Restart Unity: setsid unity
- Restart Compiz: setsid compiz --replace
- Restart X Display Manager:  sudo -s , setsid service lightdm restart

Answer (score -1):

Change your repository to main, I got the same issue when I tried installing Skype which needs these files, seems like not all repositories have been synced right.